# How to limit bad logins via apache LDAP module?

Tags: apache-httpd, ldap

We are using 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.8 on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
...
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
...
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please input password"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldapfooserver.com/ou=baar,o=foo.com?mail"
Require ldap-attribute emailAddress=somemailaddress@foo.com
...
</Directory>
...
```

And sometimes I can see that someones are trying to log in with bad password.. access.log have a lot of HTTP 401 messages.

**Question:** How can we block the IP address, if it example had ten "HTTP 401" error messages in the access.log in the past 1 hour? Or is it better to do it via iptables (limit max connections per second for an IP)? Or both?

Or better to use error.log?

```
# grep 401\.html /var/log/apache2/error.log | wc -l
3658
#
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fail2ban` package is designed to handle cases like this.  You can control the time of the ban as well as generate notifications to your administrator.